# How do I successfully traverse a pre-filled ArrayList to find the difference of each consecutive element and print it out?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, traversal

```
public class AccumulatedData {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<Double> weights = new ArrayList<Double>();

        weights.add(145.0);
        weights.add(146.5);
        weights.add(146.5);
        weights.add(147.0);
        weights.add(146.0);
        weights.add(148.0);
        weights.add(148.5);

        ArrayList<Double> printWeightChanges = getWeightChanges(weights);
        System.out.println(weights);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Double> getWeightChanges(ArrayList<Double> weights) {

        for (int i = 0; i < weights.size() - 1; i++) {
            weights.set(i, (weights.get(i + 1) - weights.get(i)));
        }

        return weights;
    }

}
```

I have attempted above to traverse all the elements of the array list and print out their respective consecutive differences (Taking index one of the array list and subtracting index zero) however, my for loop seems to traverse all elements printing their respective differences but then adds the last number of my initial array to the end of my new array list with all of the differences. How do I fix this?

ublic class PartA {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {


    ArrayList<Double> weights = new ArrayList<Double>();


    weights.add(145.0);
    weights.add(146.5);
    weights.add(146.5);
    weights.add(147.0);
    weights.add(146.0);
    weights.add(148.0);
    weights.add(148.5);


    ArrayList<Double> printWeightChanges = getWeightChanges(weights);
```

**NEW ATTEMPT:**

```
}

/**
 * Part a
 */

public static ArrayList<Double> getWeightChanges(ArrayList<Double> weights) {

    ArrayList<Double> weightDifferences = new ArrayList <Double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size() - 1; i++) {
        weightDifferences.add(i, weights.get(i + 1) - weights.get(i));

    }

    System.out.println(weightDifferences);
    return weightDifferences;


    }

}
```

This generates all sorts of errors :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 145 out of bounds for length 6
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at PartB.getWeights(PartB.java:37)
    at PartB.main(PartB.java:25)

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eldei.png)
[Code output from my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPrSE.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code (do not post links to your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of how you defined your loop limits:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weights.size() - 1; i++)
```

The loop changes one less element, than there is in an array (`i < weights.size() - 1`).

I would suggest creating another list for differences, something like this:

```
public static List<Double> getWeightChanges(ArrayList<Double> weights) {

    List<Double> diffs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size() - 1; i++) {
        diffs.add(weights.get(i + 1) - weights.get(i));
    }

    return diffs;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying to add this to my code in addition to the other list? Whenever I try to fix the for loop it seems logical to instead of do the i < weights.size() - 1; but just do i < weights.size(); however, I am met with an outofbounds exception.

Comment: Of course, so you're going to ignore my solution? Did you try replacing the method with mine?

Comment: I did not ignore your solution just was wondering if you meant to add it to my current code or to copy and implement it in instead of mine.

Comment: Why is it necessary to create another list for differences? Can't I simply just change all of the loops limits or is that not plausible?

Comment: It's easier, simply. And cleaner - otherwise you would have to remove the last element. Another point - modifying collection that you're iterating is not a good solution:)

Comment: I used your method of creating another arraylist but it still generates a load of errors. View above to see my edits.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it! It was removing the i index at the add method. Appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to output will be a different length (specifically, one data point less) than your original list. You either need to `remove()` the last element of your list, or create a new list to output with a different size.

Since your original list contains 7 doubles, and you changed the first 6, the last element of the list stays the same.

Comment: This logical explanation helps a ton thanks Alex! Could you possibly show how I could implement a new list with the code above?

Comment: Just make another `ArrayList<Double>` at the beginning of your `getWeightChanges()` method, and instead of calling `weights.set(...)` in your for loop, use something like `newList.add(...)`. Then, return `newList`. Also, note that the info in `newList` will be returned to your new `printWeightChanges` list, so you should print that out instead of `weights`.

Comment: Essentially what Andronicus already said, but I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: I understand why to create the new ArrayList now but consider viewing my edits made above. They still generate a load of errors.

Comment: Nevermind! It was simply fixing the add method! I got it thank-you so much! I might have similar questions soon about part b in this code stay tuned :)